# Form validation errors Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to show error for my registration form
Code:
When user exist I got massage Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Login_r.(rule)

Pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/5BfmPVeb

```
$config = array(
'login' => array(
    array(
        'field' => 'login',
        'label' => 'Login',
        'rules' => 'required'
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'password',
    'label' => 'Password',
    'rules' => 'required'
    )
),
'register' => array(
    array(
    'field' => 'name_r',
    'label' => 'Name',
    'rules' => 'required|alpha'
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'lastname_r',
    'label' => 'Lastname',
    'rules' => 'required|alpha'
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'login_r',
    'label' => 'Login_r',
    'rules' => 'required|callback_rule'
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'password_r',
    'label' => 'Password_r',
    'rules' => 'required|min_length[4]|max_length[12]'
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'confirm_password_r',
    'label' => 'Confirm_password',
    'rules' => 'required|matches[password_r]'
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'email_r',
    'label' => 'Email',
    'rules' => 'required|valid_email'
    ),
    array(
    'field' => 'adres_r',
    'label' => 'Adres',
    'rules' => 'required'
    )
    ),                          
);
```

Model:

```
public function register($data_db) {

$this->db->where('login',$data_db['login']);
$query = $this->db->get('users');
$row = $query->row();

if($row->login){
    $this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');
}else{
    $this->db->insert('users', $data_db);
}
```

Comment: you can put your code here, other people seem to manage

Comment: I can't becouse I have message like: "Your code is wrong formated"

Comment: and yet thousands of others manage every day.

Comment: Read this on how form validation works http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller and callbacks http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

Comment: Also when pasting code on question heres how to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Add `rule` function to your controller to check login action :

```
function rule(){

    //... 

    $data_db['login'] = $this->input->post('login_r');

    $login = $this->db->where('login',$data_db['login'])->count_all_results('users');

    if($login){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to attach it to my code. I want to check that user exist before data will send to database. Like u can see in Model. If there is a user with the same login, it should show a message